# How to config embedded Reactive Netty in Spring Boot to be able to handle get request with '|' in query

Tags: spring-webflux

I have to handle a request from the client over HTTP which has 3 pipes "|||" at the end of a request. Currently Reactive Netty thread it as a bad request so I would like to know how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| must be URL encode with %7C

There is no way around this. Who is calling the URL?

Comment: Thanks, Simon I could ask them to encrypted URI

Comment: Oh yeah encode not encrypt :) thanks again Simon and yes your answer is correct.

Comment: Great. Please mark the answer as correct and/or upvote it